# Proving that if the dual space $X^*$ of a Banach space $X$ is separable , then $X$ is separable

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces, separable-spaces

I have reading an answer [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388541/proving-that-a-banach-space-is-separable-if-its-dual-is-separable?rq=1) before , and there's something I do not understand .
For each $f_n$ in the unit ball of $X^*$ , why there exist $x_n \in X$ with $\|x_n \| \le1$ such that $f_n(x_n) \ge \frac{1}{2}$ .
I can show that for each $f_n$ , there exist $x \in X$ , $f_n(x)=a \neq 0$ . So let $x_n = \frac{x}{a}$ , we get the inequality . But how to get the desired $x_n$ with $x_n$ also in the unit ball of $X$ ?

Comment: I think that both comments and the answer there explain that the proof as written there assumes that $f_n$ belong to the unit sphere, i.e., $\|f_n\|=1$. Using that, you can get $x_n$ such that $f_n(x_n)\ge\frac12$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is false.  It should read, the unit *sphere*, not the unit ball.

Comment: Is it right that : $f $ belongs to the unit sphere means $\|f \| =1 $ and $f $ belongs to the unit ball means $\| f \| \le 1$ ?

Comment: Quite right : )