# Dual space of $\ell^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Is the dual space of $\ell^{\infty}$ contains a countable total  subset ?
I'm trying to understand the proof of Mr. Robert Whitley  "Projecting $m$ onto $c_0$" and he claims in his proof that this is true . but I think that if this is true than $\ell^{\infty}$ is separable and this is not true .
thanks for any help .

Comment: @LucasHenrique No, it is not. The dual of a non-separable space is non-separable (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388541/proving-that-a-banach-space-is-separable-if-its-dual-is-separable). This also answers the question.

Comment: You might want to check whether or not the text you are reading assumes different set theory axioms.  When the Axiom of Choice is ommitted, strange things may happen!

Comment: Proving that $(\ell^\infty)'$ is larger than $\ell^1$ needs the axiom of choice? But omitting choice we still won't get that $(\ell^\infty)'$ is separable, unless ZFC is inconsistent.

Comment: @reuns: see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019357798800396