# Collection of all open balls, centered at the same point, in a dense subset form a base for the containing set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm not even convinced that this is true, and I'm hoping that someone can help me to see why it is true.

I am attempting to prove the following:

Consider a metric space $F$ and a set $E$ that is dense in $F$. Show that the set of all open balls in E, centered at $e \in E$ and with rational radii, say $\{B(e, r_i)\}$, are a base for $F$.

To show that $\{B(e, r_i)\}$ is a base for $F$, I'd need to show that for any open set $T \subset F$ and element $t \in T$, there exists a ball $B(e, r_t) \in \{B(e, r_i)\}$ such that the following is true:

$$t \in B(e, r_t) \subset T$$

But, I don't even believe that this is true. If all of the balls in $\{B(e, r_i)\}$ must be centered at a fixed point $e$, then how can one of them always be contained in an arbitrary, open subset of $F$? The picture below is meant to illustrate my confusion.

[image]

Comment: "...centered at $e\in E$..." Shouldn't that be red as "...centered at *some* $e\in E$..."?

Comment: @drhab It seems so, but no. In the question I've got, it says "centered at $e \in E$", which I've taken to mean a fixed point $e$.

Comment: There is some controversy about the interpretation of the statement (e.g. I think it means we should take balls around all points $e \in E$, not just a fixed one, and in that thinking, I am not alone). So do you actually want to ask (i) whether you are correct that your interpretation makes the statement false, or (ii) which interpretation is the correct one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct statement is: if $E$ is dense in $F$, then the set

$$\mathcal{B} = \{B(x,r): x \in E, r \in \mathbb{Q}, r > 0\}$$ is a base for $F$.

So the radii are not a fixed point, but are members of $E$ in general. So they are centered at *some* $e \in E$..

See the implication 7 -> 1 in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2812134/4280) for details of the proof itself.

Answer (score 4):

**Minimal counterexample**. Take $E = F = \{a,b\}$ equipped with the discrete metric: 
$$
  d(x,y) = \begin{cases}
             0 & \text{if $x = y$} \\
             1 & \text{if $x \not= y$}
           \end{cases}
$$
The topology defined by $d$ is the discrete topology. However, if you take only one $e \in E$, you only get two open balls, $\{e\}$ and $F$ and these two balls do not form a basis of the discrete topology.

That being said, I fully subscribe to @drhab comment: I would understand the statement as "for *some* $e \in E$".

Answer (score 3):

You are correct! The statement, as you write, is untrue.

Every metric space is Hausdorff. Therefore, for $e$ and any other point $p$, there exist disjoint open sets $E$ and $P$ such that $e \in E, p \in P$. In particular, $e \not \in P$. However, any union of open sets, all containing $e$, contains $e$.

Therefore P is not the union of open sets containing $e$, so the balls around $e$ are not a base for the metric space (containing at least 2 points).