# Proof verification: Every separable metrizable space is second-countable.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, separable-spaces, second-countable

I am aware that this question has been asked multiple times on this site; however none of them seem to have a proof as simple as mine. So I would like to know if this is legitimate:

Let $A=\{x_n:n\in\mathbb Z_+\}$ be a countable dense set in $X$, then $\overline A=X$. So if $x\in X$, then $x\in A$ or $x\in \overline A$. Either way, any neighborhood $U$ of $x$ contains a point of $A$. So there exist positive integers $n,m$ such that $B_d(x_n,1/m)\subset U$, with $x\in B_d(x_n,1/m)$. Hence the set $$B =\{B_d(x_n,1/m):n,m\in\mathbb Z_+\}$$ 
is a countable basis for $X$.

Comment: The third sentence doesn't seem to follow from the first two sentences.

Comment: (7)$\to$(1) in [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2812134/713897) is more general, clear, simpler and complete, since you haven't shown that the ball $B_d(x_n,1/m)$ satisfies both being in $U$ and containing $x$. Maybe once one chooses $1/m$ to be inside $U$ then $x$ escaped outside of the ball. The $x_n$ must be carefully chosen to ensure that $m$ can be chosen to satisfy both.

Comment: @conditionalMethod That is a good point. How can I fix the proof? I am not interested in further generality at this point, only the claim at hand.

Comment: In the link is the argument choosing conveniently the $x_n$ first (it is called $y$ there and $A$ is called $D$). Just replace any mention of cardinality by 'countable'. Well, they worked with rational radii, which gives more freedom to choose. The radii $1/m$ can be made to work too, but one might need to choose smaller fractions of $\epsilon$ than $\epsilon/3$ and $\epsilon/2$. Explicitly, if the $r$ chosen there was $p/m$, then for your collection of balls maybe work with $\epsilon/(3p)$ and $\epsilon/(2p)$.

Comment: The $3$ and $2$ are of course, nothing special. Drawing a picture helps, because the idea is to choose the $x_n$ so close to $x$ inside the ball $B(x,\epsilon)\subset U$ that one can draw a ball with center $x_n$ an radius slightly larger than $d(x,x_n)$ and remain inside $B(x,\epsilon)$. Testing this requirement with the triangle inequality.

Comment: Got it. I will revise my proof and post it as an answer then.

Comment: @MattSamuel . You could say it follows.... eventually, after some important (missing) intermediate steps.

Comment: Your proof is incomplete, claim "with $x\in B_d(x_n,1/m)$" was not proven. For this, you could invoke the triangle inequalities. Actually, in any proof of the given theorem you **must** involve the triangle inequality since the theorem would be false if tr.ineq. were not assumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d$ be the metric on $X$. Let $A=\{x_n:n\in\mathbb Z_+\}$ be a countable dense set in $X$, then $\overline A=X$. Put $$\mathcal B = \{B_d(x,r):x\in A,r\in\mathbb Q\},$$ then $\mathcal B$ is countable as $A$ and $\mathbb Q$ are countable. Let $U$ be an open set in $X$ and $x\in U$. Because $U$ is open, we may choose $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_d(x,\varepsilon)\subset U$, and since $A$ is dense there exists $x_n\in A$ with $x_n\in B_d(x,\varepsilon/3)$. Pick $r\in\mathbb Q$ with $\varepsilon/3<r<\varepsilon/2$, then $x\in B_d(x_n,r)$ since $B_d(x_n,r)\subset B_d(x,\varepsilon/3)$. Moreover, $B_d(x_n,r)\subset B_d(x,\varepsilon)$, since if $d(y,x_n)<r$ then
$$
d(x_n,x) \leqslant d(y,x_n) + d(x_n,x) < r + r < \varepsilon.
$$
It follows that $x \in B_d(x_n,r)\subset B_d(x,\varepsilon) \subseteq U$, so that $\mathcal B$ is a basis for $X$, as desired, as of course $B_d(x_n,r) \in \mathcal{B}$ by definition.

Comment: Thank you for the edit.

Comment: @WlodAA What is funny about it? I have no formal instruction in topology, and this theorem was not "easy" for me.

Comment: peace, let's not worry about it.