# countable basis for the base of the open balls in the metric space.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $\tau$ be the topology induced from the metric space $(X, d)$.
We know that the base of the open balls in the metric space is a base for this topology.

I was wondering that if we restrict $X$ to be a countable set we can find a countable basis for the base of the open balls in the metric space.

I thought of taking the open balls with a rational radius but I was stuck proving that each open ball can be written as a finite intersection of open balls with rational radius.

I also do not think it is true.
So I think the claim above is not true but I did not find a counter example.

I would really appreciate any help.
Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you correctly, but if X is countable, wouldn't collection of $B(x,\frac{1}{n})$ for all $x\in X, \, n\in \mathbb{N}$ be countable basis for X? In this case, as x, n is countable, it would be countable union of countable sets, which would be countable.

Comment: It should be a basis of the tha base of the topology induced of the metric space. Not for X. @kim

Comment: What do you mean by *a basis for the base of the open balls*?  That is not a standard term. If you simply mean a base for the topology, then **kim** is correct; if you mean something else, you’ll have to explain what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that if $X$ has a countable dense set $D$ (so $\overline{D}=X$ and $|D| = \aleph_0$) then $\mathcal{B}=\{B(x,r)\mid x \in D, r \in \Bbb Q\}$ is a countable base for the topology of $(X,d)$.

It's proof can be found in the proof of 7 to 1 in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2812134/4280).