# How to tell if a space is second-countable

Tags: general-topology, hilbert-spaces, intuition, second-countable

*A topological space is called second-countable iff it has a countable basis.*

How to prove or at least make an assumption about whether a space does, or does NOT have countable basis? Which properties of a space can imply that it is, or isn´t second countable? Is second-countability intuitively something like "small cardinality" or "weaker countability"?

Of particular interest are $l^2$ Hilbert spaces - are they second countable? I assume not, but am not sure.

Thank you!

Comment: A metric space is second countable iff it is separable. A pre-hilbertian space is separable iff it admits a countable Hilbert basis. If X is a separable space then $L^2(X, \mathcal{B}(X),\mu)$ is also separable.

Comment: @Eevee, isn't that basis of Kronecker deltas you gave a *Hilbert* basis in the sense of linear algebra, which has little to do with the topological "basis" (I prefer "base")?

Comment: Oh, you're right, my bad. Had some wires crossed last night; sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any metric space that has a countable dense subset has a countable base, this is a classic fact. I show this and more [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2812134/4280); it could have been more succinctly stated as $w(X)=d(X)=l(X)=nw(X)$, etc. for metrisable $X$, e.g.

So $\ell^2$ and in fact all $\ell^p$ for $p\neq \infty$ are separable (so have countable weight) while $\ell^\infty$ has not, because it has a closed discrete subset of size continuum. The reasoning is: if $X$ has a countable base, this holds for all subspaces too, but a large discrete subspace does not have a countable base:

Suppose $X$ is discrete, and let $\mathcal{B}$ be a base for $X$. It's clear that for each $x \in X$, $\{x\}$ is in $\mathcal B$ because that's the only way to write to open singleton as a union of base elements. So $|\mathcal B| \ge |X|$ and so if $X$ is uncountable, $X$ does not have a countable base.

The minimal size of a base (weight) or dense set (density) etc. are just a few of the many ways to "measure" the "size" of a space. In analysis many spaces are indeed of countable base; but e.g. weak topologies on Banach spaces often are not.

Comment: So is the $l^2$ second-countable, or not? You are saying only it is separable. EDIT: Separable = has countable dense subset = has countable base = is second-countable.... Sorry, I get it.

Comment: @TerezaTizkova both because it’s metric.

Answer (score 1):

Whether a space is second-countable is a purely topological property, because it's defined in terms of its open sets (whether it has a countable basis, that is, whether its open sets are generated by a countable basis). So to find out whether a given space is second-countable, you'll have to look at it's topology. Intuitively, second-countable spaces are 'smaller' and more 'well-behaved' than ones that aren't.

For example, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is second countable since it has many countable bases for its topology - for example the open balls with rational radii. Subspaces of second countable spaces are second-countable, so all subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the subspace topology are second-countable too.

For non second-countable spaces, you can consider the uncountable product of $\mathbb{R}$ (with either the box or product topology) or the [Long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29).

Also see Henno's answer on $\ell^p$ spaces for second-countable and non second-countable Hilbert spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If a space is second-countable, the usual way to prove this will be to exhibit a specific countable basis.

If a space is not second-countable, proving this can be more intricate, and what methods are promising will vary a lot with the kind of space you are looking at. Any second-countable space is separable, and disproving separability can be easier. However, there are plenty of separable non-second-countable spaces.